# Is creating a dedicated class for a scanner a useful input solution?

Tags: java, class, input

I apologize if this is a silly question, as I am still learning Java (teaching myself).

What I am trying to do is create a sort of loan calculator in which you can choose what kind of loan you want; mortgage, car note, etc.

I was curious if creating classes that only deal with the scanner are acceptable/efficient. There are multiple methods for int entries, strings, doubles, etc. The class will be called from the main, and return whatever entry the user makes depending on what information is being requested. There will also be different catch statements in each method to deal with the different problems each method could have.

As I have been writing the program, I have come to the conclusion that there must be a more efficient method for capturing user input and catching any exceptions instead of calling the scanner I have created, adding a catch/try, and then looping for any exceptions for every individual input I ask for, which includes main menu selection and the collection of pertinent info (such as principal balance, interest rate, and loan length; all are separate calls to the scanner).

It should be noted that all of the communication with the user to make the main menu choice, input specific data, and so on, is handled in completely different classes/the main. The only calls to this class and its methods are to handle the backend request for user input and returning the (correct) value to the method in which the request was made. Below I have put the class and one of the methods from the class for my scanner use. For example, the car loan calculator class would ask the user for the principal amount, or a down payment. In that method I would call the Scan class and use the intScan method, loop through incorrect entries (incorrect data type), and return the (correct type) value back to the car loan calculator class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scan {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static boolean flag = false;

    static int intScan() { // Method for scanning for integers
        int value = 0;
        while (!flag) {
            value = scanner.nextInt();
            // catch here for exceptions, with a message
            // to the user to input the correct syntax
            if (value > -1) {
                flag = true; // Break out of loop
            }
        }
        flag = false; // Set the flag back to false for future use
        return value; // Return whatever the user input is
}
```

I would hope this would be a more elegant solution to gathering user input and dealing with exceptions, but I am not sure if it is accepted to make this sort of class in standard conventions, or if there is a better solution for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is creating a dedicated class for a scanner a useful input solution?

It is possibly useful ... if you thoughtfully design and implement an abstraction that includes prompting, telling the user what they did wrong, and retrying.

However, your current attempt doesn't cut it:

1. No prompting
2. No user reporting; i.e. "that is not a valid integer: try again".  (OK ... it looks like you *intend* to do that.)
3. It is broken because it simply retries without skipping the bad input.  That will just leads to an infinite spewing of the "try again" message.

---

Ultimately, it is up to you to decide whether what you are doing is an improvement or not.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I should have included that I have completely different classes for my different calculators, so all of the prompting for info is handled there, and the actual scanner call to get user input is solely the class I built for the scanner, so the only reporting the scanner class would do is for the user to input the correct requested data...if that makes sense. I'll update the question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I don't think so. Why not (if that's acceptable in your scenario) just read lines, and process them?

Also important: do you know if your scanner will handle mixed charset encoding gracefully? I mean charset encoding issues in Java reader classes are very very well documented throughout Stack Overflow, but I'm not so sure for these `Scanner` classes.